# Let $X \sim N(0,1) $. Calculate the density function of $Y = \sqrt{\vert X \vert}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Here is what I have done:

$P(Y\le y) = P(\sqrt{\vert X \vert}\le y)=P(\vert X \vert \le y^2) =P(\pm X \le y^2)  $.
$= P(x\le y^2) +P(-x \le y^2)=P(x \le y^2)+P(x\ge -y^2) = P(x\le y^2) +1-P(x\le -y^2)$
$ =2\phi(y^2)$.
I am unable to get anywhere by this working. I think there has to be a better method. I am also unsure whether there is any error in the steps I have done. Any guidance is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did most of the job, with some hiccups around $|X| \le y^2$.

Here is a cleaned-up version:
$$P(Y\le y) = P(\sqrt{\vert X \vert}\le y)=P(\vert X \vert \le y^2) = \\
P(-y^2 \le X \le y^2) = P(X \le y^2) - P(X < -y^2) = \Phi (y^2) - \Phi (-y^2)$$
where $\Phi ( \cdot)$ is the cdf for the standard normal.

The density function can be obtained by taking the derivative:
$$g(y) = \frac{dP(Y \le y)}{dy} = 2y \phi (y^2) + 2y \phi (-y^2) = 4y \phi(y^2)$$
where $\phi (x) = \Phi^\prime (x)$ is the density of the standard normal. The last equality follows from the symmetry of $\phi (x)$ around $x=0$.

Edit: as the derivation makes clear, the support of $Y$ is $y \ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much. The solution also says that the function is 0 for y less than 0. Why is that?

Comment: @matt: during the derivation we use $y \ge \sqrt{|X|} \ge 0$. I am adding a little edit to make this explicit.